# Do you know any tutorial for mongoDB in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just got started with nodeJS, and don't know much about it. Also I found mongoDB, and I want to use it in my project.
I searched for a tutorial, but there are all examples, that I don't completely understand.
Do yo know any tutorial that could help me?
thanks

Comment: What tutorial did you find? What did you not understand about the examples presented there?

Comment: Here's a great simple tutorial: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/9-REST-Service-with-Node.js,-MongoDB-and-Express.html

Comment: I feel the path to understanding starts from the overview (the bigger picture) of the subject and then strategically focusing down to individual pillars of fundamental concepts. So I would recommend to start at Glossary of MongoDB which will give you a fuller picture of its capabilities. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-init-script

Comment: Its a bit late but  for nodejs mongodb tutorial , you can find an article here. https://programmerblog.net/nodejs-mongodb-tutorial/

Comment: If you are looking for some Node.js-MongoDB Examples based on MongoClient, I would recommend https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-mongodb/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These should help you get started:

- http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb
  Based on old version of node, but useful walkthrough of using mongodb-native package.
- http://mongoosejs.com   A node package you can install using npm (http://npmjs.org)
  Useful package for interacting with mongoDB from Node.
- http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa The folks at dailyjs.com walk you through building a web-app with node.js and mongoDB (using mongoose). This link is the full series of posts that make up the tutorial.

Hope this helps.

**[UPDATE] 2/14/2012**
- http://howtonode.org/node-js-and-mongodb-getting-started-with-mongojs
Via howtonode.org - it's supser short but gives you the basics and is current (as this question is months old now).

**[UPDATE] 7/25/2012**
- http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/01/16/blog-rolling-with-mongodb-node-js-and-coffeescript/
Also uses coffee-script and express and goes into testing with mocha and should.js.

Comment: I think DailyJS tutorial is outdated, especially for beginners starting development with NodeJS and Mongo. Second part of the tutorial, it was already hard for me to correspond the code in the tutorial to the existing git version of the code. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well this questions was for a long time ago, the reason why I couldn't get any tutorial was that I wasn't much used to the coding styles. After months of playing with node.js and blending into the community and other developers, I can perfectly understand.

Answer (score 3):

Several of the links in the other answers are now outdated. In particular, the docs now recommend using a new top-level class called [MongoClient](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient).

10gen includes a tutorial in its documentation that helped me: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Just for the people who will see this later, at first since in the time I posted this question, I wasn't used to node.js coding style, but what helped me was this tutorial:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130926043928/http://christiankvalheim.com/post/3853862905/mongotutorial0

Answer (score 1):

http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/mongo-model

http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/mongo-model/presentations/introduction/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to a very nice series of video to get started on node and mongo.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_GNHWZHc-o

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try Mike Wilson's [Building Node Applications with MongoDB and Backbone book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026587.do).

Comment: Obviously this is a way late comment but if someone else should see this:  don't waste your money on this book - full of errors and disjointed writing.  That would explain why I am looking for better tutorials.