# How to create a database and expose it over http inorder to receie data from a sensor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, sensors

First of all, i am very much a newbie to all the technologies mentioned in this post.

I am working on something, where I have sensors, which would send their reading via HTTP post. The sensor would send the sensed value periodically over http as XML.

I found a link [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/) that explains how to create REST API.

Now in the link above it is quite clear untill the point, the author installs mongoDB. But after that point things get complex and the author didn't give an explanation what is happening in the code after.

What I am not able to figure out is,

How to create a database in node.js using mondgoDB and expose this database over http, for the sensors to send the readings.

How can I access this database in my URI's?

How can I access the date and time the data was added onto database.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I am no node.js expert but the same rules apply across the board for this kind of stuff.

You must understand that your database will not be accessible directly. Instead it will be accesses from node.js. You can add a `--rest` option to MongoDBs startup which will start a self contained RESTlet within the `mongod` program, but this is probably not an awesome idea here.

As far as I can see your jkust confused about the layers, which is common in this scenario, so to explain:

- Your sensors will POST data (I would probably change that to JSON format, it is more expressive and smaller than XML) out to your node.js server running on, i.e. `81.187.205.13`
- It will post to whatever destination your rest function to deal with this data is running, i.e. `/someawesomecontroller/notsuchagoodfunction`
- That function (as described by the tutorial you linked) will then pick up this POST, parse it and use the default method within node.js (via the driver) to insert into MongoDB. You can see the guy who wrote that tutorial doing that in the later partsd, i.e.:

  ```
  exports.findById = function(req, res) {

  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);
  db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
      collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
          res.send(item);
      });
  });
  };
  ```

So really now all you need are some tutorials on how the MongoDB driver in node.js works, here is a nice starting place: [Do you know any tutorial for mongoDB in nodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166322/do-you-know-any-tutorial-for-mongodb-in-nodejs)

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying. It sure does sounds like a great idea to start with! I will definitely look into it! And mean while i will also have a look at the mongodb driver for node.js